# Kotlin exposed DSL Query mapping

Tags: sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

- How to map select Query to a Class
- Is there any @transactional anotation to execute a query ?

  ```
  object UserRepository {
  fun getAll() : List<User> {
     return User.selectAll().map { User } // how to add it in a transaction ? // Is it the right way to map query to a Class ?
  }

  fun get(id: Int) : User? {
      return User.select { User.id eq id id}.map { User.it } // Mapping Not working
  }
  ```

Comment: I'll advise you to start from reading that blog post https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/20/a-geospatial-messenger-with-kotlin-spring-boot-and-postgresql

Answer (score 5):

I know it's late but for other people who have this question:
If you are using DSL, You can create a function in your data class for mapping purposes. for example :

```
data class User(
    val id: Int,
    val username: String,
    val password: String
) {

    companion object {

        fun fromRow(resultRow: ResultRow) = User(
            id = resultRow[UserTable.id].value,
            username= resultRow[UserTable.username],
            password = resultRow[UserTable.password]
        )
    }
}
```

and in your transaction block :

```
transaction {
        user = UserTable.select { UserTable.id eq userId }.map { User.fromRow(it) }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Mapping should be done automatically. See the documentation:

[Documentation on DAO](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO)

[Documentation on DSL](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DSL)

[Documentation on transactions](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/Transactions)

Table:

```
object Users : IntIdTable() {
  val name = varchar("name", 50)
}
```

Entity:

```
class User(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
  companion object : IntEntityClass<User>(Users)

  var name     by Users.name
}
```

Usage:

```
fun getAllUsers(): List<User> {
  Database.connect(/* ... */)
  return transaction {
    User.all().toList()
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. It says "Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: required: List<User> found: List<ResultRow>

Comment: Nevermind. I was doing `Users.all()` not `User.all()`

Answer (score 0):

My solution for extract values into HashMap, with pk as value

```
    fun getRaw(): List<HashMap<String, Any?>> {
        return transaction {
            val list = Users.selectAll().toList()

            list.map { data ->
                HashMap<String, Any?>().also { map ->
                    Users.columns.forEach {
                        if (data[it] is EntityID<*>) {
                            map[it.name] = (data[it] as EntityID<*>).value
                        } else {
                            map[it.name] = data[it]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```