# How to obtain Entity from Query with Kotlin Exposed DSL?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I`d like to use Exposed in Ktor. The simplest question is how can I get an Entity from Query options?

Such as these code:

```
/**
 * get when exist
 */
fun checkExist(phone: String): DbUser? {
    return transaction(db) {
        addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
        DbUser
            .select { DbUser.phoneNumber eq phone }
            .firstOrNull()
            .???  // how to converter ResultRow to Entity ?
    }
}
```

I want to check whether the user existing when login and get info when existing. But I can only get the reuslt with type ResultRow, How can I converter it to DbUser object?

I got a way in this [Kotlin exposed DSL Query mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50339016/kotlin-exposed-dsl-query-mapping) but it is so clumsy and time wasting. How can I accomplish it easily?

Comment: Basically you need to write a mapper from the table row to your entity. You should create a class that extends the `Table` class and a separate `data class` that is to be used as DAO. At this moment there are no options to have this mapping be performed by `exposed` automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check [wiki article](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO#read-entity-with-a-join-to-another-table).
In your case it can be resolved in two ways:

```kotlin
DbUser.select { DbUser.phoneNumber eq phone }.firstOrNull()?.let { Entity.wrapRow(it) }
```

If Entity is mapped to DbUser table:

```kotlin
Entity.find { DbUser.phoneNumber eq phone }.limit(1).firstOrNull()
```